# Android - Horizontal Page Navigation with ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-pageradapter

I am working on an app, and I want to navigate 3 pages horizontally and each page have 3 `Listviews` and respective `adapters`.

I know how to navigate images, I am referring this code. [View Pager Navigation Dots from Github source](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

But, don't know how to implement `Listview` and `adapters` for the same on each page.

Can anyone give me any idea?

Thank you in advance for the help. :)